# Type Object has no attribute

Tags: python

I am working on a program, but I am getting the error "Type object 'Card' has no attribute fileName. I've looked for answers to this, but none that I've seen is in a similar case to this.

```
class Card:
RANKS = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
SUITS = ('s', 'c','d','h')
BACK_Name = "DECK/b.gif"

def __init__(self, rank, suit):
    """Creates a card with the given rank and suit."""
    self.rank = rank
    self.suit = suit
    self.face = 'down'
    self._fileName = 'DECK/' + str(rank) + suit[0] + '.gif'

class TheGame(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Memory Matching Game")
        self.grid()

        self.BackImage = PhotoImage(file = Card.BACK_Name)
        self.cardImage = PhotoImage(file = Card.fileName)
```

Any help to solving this would be great. thanks.

Comment: What did you expect `Card.fileName` to do, and why?

Comment: I have other code that will randomly create a string to pick a card elsewhere, and then I call it in TheGame so I can assign the random image to imageLabel.

Comment: Yes, but what does that have to do with `Card.fileName`? Where do you expect this attribute to come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three **class** attributes: `RANKS`, `SUITS` and `BACK_Name`.

```
class Card:
    # Class Attributes:
    RANKS = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
    SUITS = ('s', 'c','d','h')
    BACK_Name = "DECK/b.gif"
```

You haven't defined `fileName` as a class attribute so trying to get an attribute named `fileName` will raise an `AttributeError` indicating that it doesn't exist.

This is because `fileName`, or rather, `_fileName` has been defined as an ***instance*** attribute via `self._filename`:

```
# Instance Attributes:
def __init__(self, rank, suit):
    """Creates a card with the given rank and suit."""
    self.rank = rank
    self.suit = suit
    self.face = 'down'
    self._fileName = 'DECK/' + str(rank) + suit[0] + '.gif'
```

To access this attribute you must first create an ***instance*** of the `Card` object with with `c = Card(rank_value, suit_value)`; then you can access the `_filename` via `c._filename`.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot.